# Event textChanged on dynamically created QLineEdit

Tags: qt, dynamically-generated, qlineedit

I have some code in `on_pushButton_clicked()` that creates another `QLineEdit`, and I would like to ask you how can I access the `on_lineEdit_textChanged()` event of that new `QLineEdit`.

Comment: Can you elaborate and possibly show some code? I could provide some information and maybe answer the question with some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `connect` method like this:

```
QLineEdit* le= new QLineEdit(this);
....add to layout.....
connect(le, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &)));
```